# Use autoprefixer with angular11

Tags: css, angular, sass

I am using angular11 with `SCSS`. I have the following class for example:

```
.freeSpace {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 600px;
}
```

But, when I do `ng build --prod` it does not turn to:

```
.freeSpace {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        -ms-flex: 1;
            flex: 1;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: end;
        -ms-flex-align: end;
            align-items: flex-end;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 600px;
}
```

How can I force angular to use autoprefixer?

My `angular.json` file:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "we19-app": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss",
          "skipTests": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "../backend/angular",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "we19-app:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "we19-app:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "we19-app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "we19-app:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "we19-app:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "we19-app"
}
```

I want my final `scss` files to look like the prefixer.
when I open my app in the browser, the "regular" (non-converted to autoprefixer code) scss code is presented.

**Also, when I manually attach the following to my scss:**

```
.freeSpace {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        -ms-flex: 1;
            flex: 1;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: end;
        -ms-flex-align: end;
            align-items: flex-end;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 600px;
}
```

When I do `ng build --prod` and view the app in my browser, all these "extra" scss (such as `display: -ms-flexbox`) are omitted

My .browserslistrc:

```
# This file is used by the build system to adjust CSS and JS output to support the specified browsers below.
# For additional information regarding the format and rule options, please see:
# https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#queries

# For the full list of supported browsers by the Angular framework, please see:
# https://angular.io/guide/browser-support

# You can see what browsers were selected by your queries by running:
#   npx browserslist

last 1 Chrome version
last 1 Firefox version
last 2 Edge major versions
last 2 Safari major versions
last 2 iOS major versions
Firefox ESR
not IE 11 # Angular supports IE 11 only as an opt-in. To opt-in, remove the 'not' prefix on this line.
```

Comment: Why would you build an angular app and create CSS for browsers that can't run an angular app (`-ms-flex` is only used by IE10, `-webkit-box` is used by chrome version ~20)  These browsers can't run your angular app, they don't understand the Javascript for it. So no reason to have it in your CSS.

Comment: @cloned I want to support mobile native apps. Simply, when I open the app in Safari, It is missing the `display: -webkit-box` so I don't get a flex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can modify the `.browserslistrc` file as follows

```
Safari 6
IE 10
```

This results in the following css

```
.freeSpace {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: end;
    -ms-flex-align: end;
    align-items: flex-end;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 600px;
}
```

Comment: so should I replace `last 2 Safari major versions` with `Safari 6`?

Comment: yes, simply replace `not IE 11` with `IE 10` and `last 2 Safari major versions` with `Safari 6`

Answer (score 0):

If you check [the support page for angular](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support), you will see it only supports recent browser.

So if you build your app it will only add necessary prefixes. If you check [for support on flexbox](https://caniuse.com/?search=flexbox) you will see that all current browsers support `display: flex` . `display: -ms-box` is only supported by IE10, which is not supported by angular. So it doesn't make sense to bloat your CSS with unnecessary prefixes. That's why it get's filtered out.

Comment: But how come angular not support `Safari` browser?

Comment: Safari understands `display: flex` just fine according to the link I posted. Which version of safari do you need the prefix for?